# word vba insert object from button

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking to insert an object, a word doc, into an existing word 2013 document from a button. I've got as far as creating the button and and tried various pieces of code in VBA but can't find any walkthroughs on something that I would've thought would be quite simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This inserts a word object. You can easily adapt it to import an existing word file as well.

```
Sub InsertWordObject()
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Word.Document.12", _
        FileName:="", LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90150000-0011-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe" _
        , IconIndex:=13, IconLabel:="Microsoft Word Document"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!